# IO7: keyboard become transparent if used in UIAlert view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova, ios7, uialertview

How can i disable transparency of keyboard in IOS7?

I am using phonegap application and used below code to show prompt:

```
UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[dialog setDelegate:self];
[dialog setTitle:@"Location"];
[dialog setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enter Location"]];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Enter"];
dialog.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

dialog.tag = 7;

UITextField *textField = [dialog textFieldAtIndex:0];

[textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",marker.snippet]];


[dialog show];
[dialog release];
```

Please help me
Thanks :)

Comment: In IOS7 phonegap app, for webview keyboard is not transparent by default,But after UIAlertView keyboard become transparent for webview,

How can i make it non transparent for Webview.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method in ViewWillAppear

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault];
```

or

set in UIAlertView:

```
 UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
 textField.keyboardAppearance=UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
```

Comment: Not Working
Still Showing transparent keyboard

Comment: In iOS 7, We Can't change keyboard transparent, they didn't give the permission to change.But you can change the appearance. That you can see in search bar in iOS7 Home.

Comment: Solution for these,you can create own customize keyboard..in my point of view.

Comment: Thanks For Solution.                                                    
But Keyboard become transparent only after UIAlterView Prompt appear.
Is it possible to create custom Alert View.

Comment: Or All UIText views are using transparent keyboard.

Comment: yes u can create a custom alertview. There is lot of example available in net.

Comment: Still Not working, Transparent keyboard is still there?

Comment: Then You can try the customized keyboard.it may be helpful for you

Comment: Is it possible to create customize keyboard for WebView?
I didn't find anything.